# Unify colour settings across vim and gvim

Tags: unix, vim, colors, gvim

My `vim` and `gvim` have different colour settings.

[image: vim]

[image: gvim]

**I want to use the same colour settings in both.**

I checked I am not using any **.vimrc** or **.gvimrc** configuration file at the moment.

How do I unify the colour settings? (preferably use gvim's colour settings in vim also)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want both vim and gvim to use the same color scheme, place the configuration in .vimrc. Unless overridden in .gvimrc, gvim will use whatever is specified in .vimrc:

> colorscheme XYZ

You can't have vim and gvim look exactly the same; vim, running in a terminal, doesn't have control over background color. Also, unless you're running a 256-color terminal, gvim has a lot more colors available to it for use in color schemes (that color schemes may or may not use). If you want them to look exactly the same, you may need to create/custimize your own theme.

So, if you have a terminal which supports 256 colors, set

> export TERM=xterm-256color

before running vim and hope that the colorscheme XYZ looks the same in vim as in gvim :)

Comment: What should I write in my `.vimrc` for it to use the default colour configuration (so that both vim and gvim use the *same* default colour configuration)?

Comment: @eSKay: "colorscheme xyz". the problem is that your terminal must support the same colors the colorscheme wants. your best bet is to use a 256-color-terminal with setting the environment variable TERM=xterm-256color (for example).